# Getting a request timeout on Heroku with passportJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose, redis

I've been struggling with this all night but I haven't found an answer. I created an application which uses Passport JS for authentication. The users are saved in a MongoDB database, works perfectly on my local machine.

For that reason, I attempted to upload the app on Heroku. I added the mlab add-on and imported the data from my local database. When I visit the mlab dashboard the data is there.

The problem is that when I fill the form and hit enter, the app doesn't do anything and the in the console of the web browser the following error appears: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)". I don't know what it's wrong and I need to fix it.

Among all the things I've read I think that a possible error could be that I'm not using things like connect-redis or connect-mongo (don't know which is best) with express-session. This is my code (middlewares):

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(session({
    name: 'session',
    secret: '53kre7',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}))
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
```

So I really hope you can help me because I want to learn how to do it right. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. Heroku named the variable as MONGODB_URI while in my code I had MONGOLAB_URI. So I wasn't pointing to a real database. Problem solved.